# Multiple CN LDAP integration in Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, ldap

I want to use multiple CN names in LDAP configurations.

I tried to use
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "CN=GROUP_NAME1,OU=MSG Distribution Groups,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX"

How can I allow multiple groups in CN?

Thanks in advance.